# Prevent arrow keys from going to the previous/next cell

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When working with Jupyter notebooks inside of Visual Studio Code (using the Python extensions by Microsoft), it is possible to configure the application as to prevent the arrow keys from exiting the current cell?

Basically, I would like NOT to go to the previous or next cell when I move inside of an editable cell (code or markdown) using the arrow keys.

---

Solution by @Michael Erickson discussed in the comments:

- open Settings (not json)
- search "Feature/Notebook navigation"
- the option shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is:
**Notebook › Navigation: Allow Navigate To Surrounding Cells**

Description:
When enabled cursor can navigate to the next/previous cell when the current cursor in the cell editor is at the first/last line.

When you first use Visual Studio Code with a notebook it asks you this question, and you have virtually no chance of remembering the setting.  Of course this is before you have a chance to realize that this is a horrible option for many coders. Using the down arrow does not move to the end of the line in the last cell, but to whereever your cursor last happened to be in the next cell.

They are cells for a reason, and treating them as if they are just paragraphs may make sense to a non-coder who is looking at them as if they were documentation.  For a coder, cells are collections of small files, not paragraphs, and pressing down arrow always goes to the end of the line.  Navigation between them should be explicit, certainly not something that can accidentally be done when trying to add a line.

If there were an option to add an empty line at the end of the cell, to continue the cell, this would be fine, but pressing ctrl+Enter runs the cell, instead of opening a new line, as it does in the code editor.  It isn't always clear when you are on the last line, as the bottom border of the cells is **huge**, so half the time you press down arrow just to move to the border space, only to find you have the hit up arrow ten times to get back there, or **escape+uparrow+enter+end** to get to where you wanted to be in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! However, after disabling that option, how do I move to the previous/next cell using only the keyboard? As a marginal note: I think that most of the Python ecosystem has been designed for non-coders.

Comment: It is similar to Vim, you press Esc to leave cell editing and then your arrow keys navigate.  I think the navigation and keyboard shortcuts are a little clearer in Jypyter notebooks outside of VS Code, but they have done a good job supporting them in the ide.

Comment: Yesterday I decided to try your suggestion, but cannot find the settings. Were you speaking about visual studio code?

Comment: Yes, good catch.  I am using Visual Studio Code here, 1.68.1.  It took me a long time to locate the settings as well, when searching via most keywords it did not show up in the filtered list.  Instead, I found it in settings under "Features/Notebook".  Also, searching for "Navigation" or "Surrounding" under the settings shows it.

Comment: May be there is a bug in VSC. If I open Settings (not in json mode) and search "Features", no options for notebooks show up. If I then search "Features/Notebook" some options show up, but they do not include that for Navigation etc. I need to search "Feature/Notebook navigation" and the option is there. A little mess. Thanks!

Comment: When using vim mode, I am still able to move to the next cell. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

This feature does not work on `Vim` mode. I can still move the cursor to a different cell when I am in the `normal` mode.